Python: "IndexError: string index out of range" error
I'm new to Python and decided to try and make a program that takes an input text and reverses it:
word = input("type a thingy: ")
length = len(word)
i = 0
out=[]
while i < length:
    out +=(word[length - i])
    i += 1
print(str(out))

However, when I ran the program, it gave me an Index Error for line 5.
    out +=(word[length - i])
IndexError: string index out of range

I looked up the problem and nothing recommended seemed to work. I tried changing the while loop to a for loop but also nothing changed.

A better way to reverse a string is by taking the word and slice it. (like shown here)
word = word[::-1]

Python allows you not to worry about indexes. Try "for letter in word:".

This happens because an index goes from 0 to length - 1, but in the first iteration of the loop you use length - 0, so just length, which is past the end of the text. Add - 1 to the brackets:
out += (word[length - i - 1])

